# Impossible situation while doing OLAP

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, pentaho, cube

I have a normal star schema with about 5 dimension and 1 fact. It's about book rental store.

When I'm analyzing using Pentaho Analyzer. I encoutered very weird situation that I think can't be happen. I dragged my 'Book Rent Count' measurement and drag 'Quarter' field from Date Dimension. It should be impossible to show duplicate 'Quarter' but it does :

```
Quarter        Book Rent Count
1              1
3              1
4              2
4              1
4              1
4              2
```

What condition should keep it to NOT group the Quarter 4? Be it a Q4 from different year it should group nicely.

This happen with other field too. Something is keeping it from grouping. In the database I already have utf8_general_ci collation for each table.

(This happen exactly the same when I tried using Saiku to analyze instead of Pentaho User Console.)

Answer (score 3):

Drag in Year as well and it will show you why you have duplicates.  Those duplicate quarters are for different years.

The "unique names" option in the schema xml controls this behaviour.

If you genuinely want to group by quarter regardless of year, then you'll need a hierarchy which doesn't have Year at the top. (Although not 100% sure how useful this would really be)